# SSAS: How to preserve null value in microsoft BIDS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, bids

I am trying to create a cube in microsoft analysis services, but i failed to preserve the null values. It always return as 0. In my database (SQL Server 2005) i have two fact tables and two dimension table and a date table. In my fact table I have 0 values, null values and some positive values.

Here is what i have done so far

[image]

In the above picture the values for Bigeye tuna and other tuna is null, but it is showing as 0, the value for EEZ is 0 in the database and it is shown correct. I have set nullprocessing to preserve as shown below

[image]

When I set # as the format string the value for EEZ is also gone.

[image]

[image]

Here is the database table

[image]

I want it to show the value of EEZ(11) as 0, and remove the values of Bigeye Tuna(9) and other tuna(10) as it is null in the database also.

So can anyone tell me how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work w/o additional format settings. Are you sure there are no mixed values 0 and NULLs?

Here is my example, last column is a source for fake measure with zeros and NULLs:

[image: ZeroNullMeasures_1SQL]

Here is measure settings w/o format:

[image: ZeroNullMeasures_2Measure]

Finally, here is browser with empty cells turned on:

[image: ZeroNullMeasures_3Browser]

Everything should work as above.

Maybe it's connected with hidden level. Could you temporary turn `EEZ` lower level back and see value there?

Grand total shows zeros in Excel instead of 10.3K, 104.5K and 114.8K. Is there some SCOPE, which manage totals or other parts?

And also please check mixed 0 and NULL values for the same group/member.